# Вставка текущей даты при создании записи?

Tags: access

Используется
access 2016
MySq -5,7-x64

Используются внешние таблицы.

Вопрос.
1. Как сделать чтобы при создании записи автоматически проставлялась текущая дата в поле "data_sozd"?
2. Как сделать чтобы при смене статуса автоматически проставлялась текущая дата в поле "data_status"?

**[Ссылка](http://transfiles.ru/a775l)** на файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Access для этого используются т.н. макросы данных: в конструкторе таблиц на вкладке Конструктор выбираете пункт Создать макросы данных > После вставки (После обновления) и там строите выражение Изменить запись > Задать поле, указываете имя поля, значение = Date().

Я, правда, не уверен, что такой подход работает с внешними таблицами. Даже так, скорее всего, не работает. В этом случае надо внести изменения на стороне MySQL: для поля data_sozd установить значение по умолчанию `ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE data_sozd DATE NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`; для обновления data_status требуется создать триггер на обновление данных:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name 
BEFORE UPDATE ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  SET new.request_plan_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; 
END;
```

Здесь же, во избежание перезаписи значения data_sozd, можно добавить строчку
`SET NEW.data_sozd = OLD.data_sozd;`